# How to set the footer to the bottom of the page in react using tailwind css responsively?

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

For the larger screens, the footer goes up and there is some padding under the footer. How can I fix it?

**Code**

```
    <footer className="absolute w-full flex flex-col mt-auto text-center lg:text-left bg-off-white text-dark-blue">
        <div className="w-full flex flex-wrap  justify-center items-center lg:justify-evenly p-6 border-t border-gray-300">
         footer body
        </div>
    </footer>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest going for something like this, is pretty straight forward:

```html
<!--- This is the main container (wraps the entiner page)--->
<div class="min-h-screen bg-black flex flex-col">
  <!--- Some content --->
  <!--- This will take as much height as possible --->
  <div class="bg-gray-800 text-white flex-1">Hello</div>
  
  <!--- Footer --->
  <!--- This will be left at the bottom of the page --->
  <div class="py-4 text-white">Some content in Footer</div>
</div>
```

Feel free to play with this example: [Tailwind Playground](https://play.tailwindcss.com/MD8XmaoR9P)